# Output from a powershell script displayed in Windows Form?

Tags: winforms, powershell, scripting

My goal:

Write a quick gui program that lets you select a date from a date picker, sends that date as a command line argument to a powershell script, and displays the output of that script. I would prefer the output to be in real time, not redirected to a file then displayed.

Also, I have been writing the gui portion in powershell aswell using winforms, but I can switch to C# or something else.

I tried searching, but I couldn't find much on running a PS script within a winForm.

Thanks!
-Brodie

---

#### EDIT 1

I apologize, I guess the question is a bit broad. I'll try to describe in more detail what I want -

I want to have a windows form that contains a date picker and other options (Stuff I can do myself). Then, when the RUN button is pressed, the area in the bottom (Outlined in RED below) will display the OUTPUT of a totally seperate Powershell script.

[image: example win form]

Please let me know if I can clarify better.

Comment: Your question as posted is too broad. See question guidelines.

Comment: @stuartd : OP does not necessarily want to use C#. Rudedog9d, you should try, and post some code so we can help.

Comment: I guess a good example of what I might want is an installation - how installers can show you each process they are performing in real time. How does that work?

Answer (score 3):

A very simple powershell using winforms (as i understood you'd prefer):

This just takes a date, run a command (echo) and gets the output. I think you can work the rest out..

(Edited the answer to better suit the edited question)

```
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms")
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Drawing") 

$objForm = New-Object Windows.Forms.Form 

$objForm.Text = "Select a Date" 
$objForm.Size = New-Object Drawing.Size @(500,400) 
$objForm.StartPosition = "CenterScreen"

$objForm.KeyPreview = $True

$objForm.Add_KeyDown({
    if ($_.KeyCode -eq "Escape") 
        {
            $objForm.Close()
        }
    })

function btnClick
{
            $dtmDate=$objCalendar.SelectionStart.ToString("yyyyMMdd")

            Write-Host "Date selected: $dtmDate"


        $ps = new-object System.Diagnostics.Process
        $ps.StartInfo.Filename = "cmd.exe"
        $ps.StartInfo.Arguments = " /c echo Date = $dtmDate"
        $ps.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = $True
        $ps.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = $false
        $ps.start()
        $ps.WaitForExit()
        [string] $Out = $ps.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();

        Write-Host "Output $Out"
        $label.text = "$Out"    
}

$button = New-Object Windows.Forms.Button
$button.text = "RUN"
$button.Location = New-Object Drawing.Point 170,130
$button.add_click({btnClick})
$objForm.controls.add($button)

$label = new-object system.windows.forms.label
$label.text = ""
$label.Location = New-Object Drawing.Point 0, 180
$label.Size = New-Object Drawing.Point 200,30
$objForm.controls.add($label)

$objCalendar = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.MonthCalendar 
$objCalendar.ShowTodayCircle = $False
$objCalendar.MaxSelectionCount = 1
$objForm.Controls.Add($objCalendar) 

$objForm.Topmost = $True

$objForm.Add_Shown({$objForm.Activate()})  
[void] $objForm.ShowDialog()
```

Comment: I have seen this piece of code (or very similar), although I appreciate it! See my edits for more details on what I'm looking for

Comment: Hi. You are probably right, just took some code online and pasted together to give you a quick answer :)   A better suited answer on its way..

Answer (score 0):

The steps to run a Powershell script from a Winforms application, briefly summarized, are:

1. Use the System.Management.Automation assembly.
2. Initiate the PowerShell class, something like: `using (PowerShell ps = Powershell.Create()) { //your code here }`
3. Use the `AddScript()` and `AddParameter()` methods to add scripts and parameters.
4. Use the `Invoke()` (synchronous) or `BeginInvoke()` (asynchronous) methods to execute the script.

This blog post contains a full tutorial: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kebab/2014/04/28/executing-powershell-scripts-from-c/